# Script to check the TIME on all servers listed in %FILENAME%

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, scripting

I would like to check the time on a bunch of windows 2003 and 2008 servers listed in an excel file, i.e. (serverlist.txt) and output to another file.

Is this possible.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried out anything, this is the script im working off. :: Window TITLE
                title DST check
                cls
                echo off
                cls

:: Specify the file containing the list of hostnames to check (one hostname per line)
set FILENAME=\\irl-filer2\serverlist.txt
                
:: Loop Through file
for /F %%A in (%FILENAME%) do call :CHECK_TIME %%A
goto :eof

:CHECK_TIME 
                for /f "tokens=1-7 delims= " %%a in ('net time \\%1 ^| grep Current') do (set HOST=%%d& set TIME=%%g)
                echo %HOST% %TIME%

Comment: There is a reference to grep there which I obviously need to change so dont shoot me over posting a linux command.

Comment: Why do you want to check the time?  What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the servernames are in input.txt, you can run this command.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (input.txt) do net time \\%%a|find /i "%%a">>result.txt
```

Comment: Great, I had copied grep to a folder on my c:\ and my script above with servers listed in serverlist.txt without any spaces and it didn't work. With your script  do the servernames need to be in comma delimited format or line by line, thanks.

Comment: That works perfect, needs "input.txt" to be a line by line file. thank you.